# How can i pass multiple variables in the Url for the Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to pass two variables in the url to my Spring Controller.

I'm trying to achieve this using the following code. 
The controller though reads just the second param.

What am i missing here?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/getVars")
public class SpringServiceController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Id/{Id}/Name/{Name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getGreeting(@PathVariable String Id, @PathVariable String Name) {
         //Both id and name now holds Name variables value. 
         System.out.println("Id: "+ Id + " >> Name: " + Name);

    }
}
```

i/p:  `localhost:8080/service/getVars/Id/111/Name/222`

o/p: `Id: 222 >> Name: 222`

Expected o/p: `Id: 111 >> Name: 222`

Comment: can you try `@PathVariable("Id") String Id, @PathVariable("Name") String Name` in your method signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might depend on the way you are compiling your source code. If the parameter names are not included in the byte code, I don't think the behavior of [`@PathVariable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) without a `value` attribute is defined. Add it explicitly

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Id/{Id}/Name/{Name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getGreeting(@PathVariable(value = "Id") String Id, @PathVariable(value = "Name") String Name) {
```

Comment: @prabugp trigger happy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @PathVariable to pass any number of values to the controller. You can read this simple [example](http://www.javabeat.net/pathvariable-template-patterns-spring-mvc/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring multiple @pathVariable for each of the variables in URL, you can make use of Map interface to pass the multiple variables from URL.
For example :

```
 @RequestMapping("/student/{rollNo}/{class}")
 public void college(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariables) {
    String rollNo = pathVariables.get("rollNo");
    String classNo = pathVariables.get("class");
 }
```